How many unique permuted strings of length 5 can be formed from the characters of string "balloon"?
If the permuted strings would be of length 7, equalling given string length, it would have been simple, that is $$ \frac{7!}{2! \cdot 2!} $$  equalling 1260. Each permutation included all characters of string balloon, making it easy to count number of permutations, by simply dividing the number of repetitions.
In case of length 5 < 7 some permutations may contain repeating characters l and o $(blloo, lbloo,...)$, or even not $(bllon, nalob,...)$ . In that case, what would be a good way to count the number of permutations ? How to count the number of permutations with repeating, and non repeating characters, or even excluding few repeating characters ?

I suppose you already know that you can make cases, e.g. ll or oo together and three single letters or both ll and oo together and one single letter, etc.
But if you are looking for a good general method:

let the exponent of $x$ represent how many times a particular letter can occur, e.g. in $ABBCCC$, $A$ can occur $0$ or $1$ time $(x^0+x^1)$, $B's$ can occur $0,1,\;or\;2$ times $(x^0+x^1+x^2)$ etc.

you know that if you multiply two polynomials in $x$, the exponents get added up, e.g. $(1+x^2)\cdot (1+x^3)$, the term with the highest degree would be $x^5$

you also know that if a letter occurs, say thrice in a word, you need to divide by $3!$ to count the arrangements


So knowing the above points, we can represent all possible permutations of length $5$ in the word  balloon by the coefficient of $x^5$ in
$\small{5!(x^0+x^1)(x^0+x^1)(x^0+x^1+\frac{x^2}{2!})(x^0+x^1+\frac{x^2}{2!})(x^0+x^1)}$
the terms in parantheses representing how many times  $b, a, l, o, n$ can be used
which, of course, can be written in condensed form as
$5!(1+x)^3(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})^2$, which on expansion gives
$690$ as the coefficient of $x^5$
So we have $690$ possible permutations of length $5$
Welcome to the world of exponential generating functions !

Simplest (but not that elegant) is case work:

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~~2 ~Ls, 2 ~Os ~\text{used}}$
$$3 \times \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} = 90.$$
That is, $~3~$ choices for the off-letter, then $~10~$ choices for positioning the L's, then $~3~$ choices for positioning the O's.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~~2 ~Ls, 1 ~O ~\text{used}}$
$$3 \times \binom{5}{2} \times 3! = 180.$$
That is, $~3~$ choices for the $~2~$ other letters, then $~10~$ choices for positioning the L's, then $~3!~$ choices for positioning the remaining $~3~$ distinct letters.

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~~2 ~Ls, 0 ~Os ~\text{used}}$
$$\binom{5}{2} \times 3! = 60.$$
That is,  $~10~$ choices for positioning the L's, then $~3!~$ choices for positioning the remaining $~3~$ distinct letters.

$\underline{\text{Case 4:} ~~1 ~L, 2 ~Os ~\text{used}}$
By symmetrical considerations, the same as the Case 2 enumeration of
$$180.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 5:} ~~1 ~L, 1 ~O ~\text{used}}$
$$5! = 120$$
That is, you have $~5~$ distinct letters to permute.

$\underline{\text{Case 6:} ~~0 ~Ls, 2 ~Os ~\text{used}}$
By symmetrical considerations, the same as the Case 3 enumeration of
$$60.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Summary}}$
$$90 + 180 + 60 + 180 + 120 + 60 = 690.$$
